# Blog Search API in Java

Tags: java, search, blogs

Can anyone point out a blog search API in Java ? Looked at the Bloglines search API but could not find a Java-based API there.

Answer (score 1):

The Bloglines Search API is language independent (as is a Web Service), you can hit their API from Java for sure. (more [here](http://www.bloglines.com/services/api/search)).

Anyway, I guess that what you are looking for is for a Java Library for access their Search API, probably will work for you [JBloglines](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jbloglines/) (is the first hit on a google result, no idea of how good is it).

Good luck!

Comment: JBloglines "last commit on 2004-12-02" that says it all

Comment: Ops, you are totally right. Just copy the first hit of google (as said before), anyway, If you are writing Java should be eassy enough write a class for that WS.

Comment: Thanks for the help. You were correct, its easy enough to hit the search api from Java code and get the results. I just did that and its pretty much what I want at this time :)